# Linear regression with smoothed time-series as independent and dependent variables

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, kernel-smoothing

I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding something quite obvious here but I'm rather confused.

I have multiple time-series that have been smoothed with a gaussian kernel. My goal is to regress the time-series from a condition 3 ($y_t$) on the time-series from conditions 1 & 2 ($x^1_t$ and $x^2_t$).

More formally, this would be my regression setup:

$$
\tilde{y_t} = \beta_0 + \beta_1\tilde x^1_t + \beta_2\tilde x^2_t + \epsilon_t. 
$$

Both $\tilde x^1_t$ and $\tilde x^2_t$ are autocorrelated (because of the smoothing), but is it a problem when running the linear regression? To what extent will it influence the recovery of my $\beta$s knowing that my errors are therefore probably serially autocorrelated?

As both $\tilde x^1_t$ and $\tilde x^2_t$ are strongly correlated, I have been advised to remove the mean of my dependent and independent variables (i.e. $(\tilde x^1_t + \tilde x^2_t + \tilde y_t)/3$) from my independent and dependent variable before running the linear regression. For example, define $\tilde y^*$ as

$$
\tilde y^* = \tilde y_t - (\tilde x^1_t + \tilde x^2_t + \tilde{y_t})/3
$$

and run the regression on $\tilde y^*$.
I don't see how this might help and find it strange to "inject" the dependent variable as one of my predictors.

This is my first question here and I hope it's not too confusing nor I missed anything. I have tried looking over other posts ([such as this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26133/is-there-a-difference-between-an-autocorrelated-time-series-and-serially-autocor)) but couldn't really draw any link with my problem at hand.

Comment: It could be helpful to distinguish between raw and smoothed values e.g. by writing $x$ and $\tilde x$ (`$\tilde x$`), respectively. Are you interested in the coefficients of $y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1,t}+\beta_2 x_{2,t}+\epsilon_t$ but you are running $y_t=\tilde\beta_0+\tilde\beta_1\tilde x_{1,t}+\tilde\beta_2\tilde x_{2,t}+\tilde\epsilon_t$ instead? Also, I do not fully follow the part starting with *I have been advised to...*, especially *to "inject" the dependent variable as one of my predictors*.

Comment: There's some discussion and illustrative example of smoothing making spurious correlation (and hence, spurious regression) worse here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133155/how-to-use-pearson-correlation-correctly-with-time-series/133171#133171

Comment: Thanks for this useful link. I also edited the question, it is hopefully clearer now.

Comment: Your tildes were flying quite high, so I lowered them for you. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: I was thinking about looking at cointegration [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointegration), could this be one way to solve my issue ?

Comment: Are your series integrated? If not, there is no place for cointegration.